# Borrow/get the wordings?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request

In qualitative research (e.g., thematic analysis) often multiple text extracts are grouped into a theme. The wording of the theme sometimes is based on the wordings of the original texts. To describe this I first came up with the following sentence:

> Most of the themes borrowed the wordings from the original texts

I want to ask whether the sentence above is correct or natural in English or not?  if the sentence is correct, could someone provide alternative sentences?

Comment: Please reword your question. It is not clear exactly what you are asking. To what quoted sentence do you refer? What are the occurrences about which you ask? About what sentence do you ask _"if the sentence is correct, could you provide alternative sentences..."_?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Sorry I reworded the question.

Comment: It is grammatical English, but whether it is appropriate to its intended use is impossible to say.  It might be better to write: _"Most of the themes **are adapted from** the wordings **in** the original texts."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's grammatical, but unclear, not entirely natural, and a little informal. Speaking as someone trained in this sort of analysis.

I would say "**their** wordings", rather than "the wordings", because we're talking about the wording *of* the themes, so a relative possessive is appropriate.

Then there's the choice of verb, ***borrowed***. This is fine, but it's a little informal in this instance. I would simply say ***took***, or ***take***.